# MS Word: switch off all auto correction tools

Tags: microsoft-word, autocorrect

I appreciate the usefulness of auto correction tools, but personally I prefer software that does only what I explicitly want it to do. Therefore, I would like to switch off all auto correction tools in MS Word 2010 (and in all other MS Office programs).

I have found the settings for AutoCorrect and disabled everything:

[image]

However, the software still auto corrects the first symbols of my bullet lists if I change the symbol of a latter one:

[image]

(I want the first symbol to be a dot and the second to be an arrow)

Is there any way of turning this off?

I am using MS Word 2010.

Comment: That's auto-formatting, not auto-correction. Two different things. Notice the "Control AutoFormat Options" option? Have you tried using that (or the Autoformat tab shown in your screenshot) to set the AutoFormat options?

Comment: Yes, I have unchecked all boxes in all sub-tabs of AutoCorrect

Comment: As Techie has pointed out Auto- **correct** and **Format** are **different** things, you are fighting with **formatting**.

Comment: I know, but in MS Word they are all summarized under the global name AutoCorrect, see screenshot. That's why I used the name here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Open new document -- > click on numbered list --> type value 'J' --> enter keystroke --> click on numbered list (un-selects), then on bullet list and input 'G'. Rinse and repeat.

[image: example]

Edit: Fixed solution

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Unfortunately, it does not help (even if I uncheck all mark error tags). I am wondering why this could be a solution, because I can't see a correlation between marking grammar errors and auto-correcting bullet lists.

Comment: Understandable, have you gone through all the Auto tabs in the auto correct options?

Comment: Yes, and I have unchecked every tag available.

Comment: Try under Advanced -> Editing options -> un-check show autocomplete suggestions.

Comment: this did not help for my problem

Comment: What is the symbol characters being used, I'm trying to reproduce and I'm having difficulty.

Comment: Actually it is the same with any symbol. Choose bullet list, type 'a', enter, type 'b', chose another symbol. It will change the symbol of line 'a' as well.

Comment: see updated solution

Comment: It still does not work, it only does not show the symbol with the lightning bolt anymore. Did you achieve your result without ctrl+z or something similar to undo the auto-formatting of the first number?

Comment: Not particularly, I did everything I said above and very easily clicked on the symbol that I used when I was done with it, then clicked on the next symbol. The previous symbol then is not changed (did not change the formatting and did not pop up the box asking to change the formatting).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/16015/discussion-between-user3582129-and-mr-hargrove).